# Saving data in local storage

Tags: javascript, beginner, design-patterns

I have written a small library for saving data on local storage. I am still a learner and I am not sure whether my code is OK for a production level application.

```
function AppStorage (aName) {
    "use strict";

    var prefix  = aName;

    var saveItem = function (key, value) {

        if (!key || !value) {

            console.error("Missing parameters \"key\" and \"value\"");    

            return false;
        }

        if (window.localStorage && window['localStorage']) {

            try {

                localStorage.setItem(prefix + '_' + key, JSON.stringify(value));

            } catch (e) {

                return false;

            }

        } else  {

            return false;

        }

    }

    var getItem = function (key) {

        if (!key) {

            console.error("Missing parameter \"key\"");    

            return false;
        }

        if (window.localStorage && window['localStorage']) {
            try {

                localStorage.getItem(prefix + '_' + key);

            } catch (e) {

                return false;

            }

        } else  {

            return false;

        }

    }

    var removeItem = function (key) {

        if (!key) {

            console.error("Missing parameter \"key\"");

            return false;
        }

        if (window.localStorage && window['localStorage']) {

            try {
                return localStorage.removeItem(prefix + '_' + key)
            } catch (e) {
                return false;
            }

        } else  {

            console.log("Browser doen not support HTML5 Web Storage");

        }

    }

    return {
        set: function (key, value) {
            return saveItem(key, value);
        },
        get: function () {
            return getItem(key, item);
        },
        remove: function () {

        }
    }

}

var as = new AppStorage ('MyApp');
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Structure:

Instead of having a function encompass everything, consider using a `prototype` constructor, or if you can use ECMAScript 2015, use the `class` structure.

By using the `prototype` structure your code would look something like the following:

```
var AppStorage = function(name){
    this.prefix = name;
}
AppStorage.prototype.saveItem = function(key, value){

}
AppStorage.prototype.getItem = function(key){

}
AppStorage.prototype.removeItem = function(key){

}
var AS = new AppStorage('myName');
AS.getItem('thing');
```

Which removes the need for blocks like the following:

> ```
> return {
>     set: function (key, value) {
>         return saveItem(key, value);
>     },
>     get: function () {
>         return getItem(key, item);
>     },
>     remove: function () {
>
>     }
> ```

---

### Things to improve upon:

- `console.error`: instead of that, use `throw new Error()` instead.
- There's a consistent use of extraneous empty lines, remove them. They're pointless and waste space.
- When you `return` the aliases for the functions, the `remove` function is left empty, if that is the desired case, then it should simply be removed, otherwise, you forgot to link the `remove` function.
- `window.localStorage && window['localStorage']`: uh, that's identical; you can access object properties via the `.` method, or `['']` method.
- `prefix + '_' + key`: it would be easier/better to just append the underscore when you define the prefix initially.
- `removeItem` is the only function that doesn't just `return false` if `localStorage` does not exist. Consider incorporating the error message in every function, or just check for `localStorage` on initialisation.

---

### With those changes in mind...

... here's your updated code:

```
var AppStorage = function(name) {
    if (!(this instanceof AppStorage)) {
        throw new Error("AppStorage must be invoked with new!");
    }
    if (!window.localStorage){
        throw new Error("Browser does not support HTML5 Web Storage");
    }
    this.prefix = name + '_';
}
AppStorage.prototype.save = function(key, value) {
    if (!key || !value) {
        throw new Error("Missing parameters \"key\" and \"value\"");
    }
    try {
        localStorage.setItem(this.prefix + key, JSON.stringify(value));
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
};
AppStorage.prototype.get = function(key) {
    if (!key) {
        throw new Error("Missing parameter \"key\"");
    }
    try {
        localStorage.getItem(this.prefix + key);
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
};

AppStorage.prototype.remove = function(key) {
    if (!key) {
        throw new Error("Missing parameter \"key\"");
    }
    try {
        return localStorage.removeItem(this.prefix + key);
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
};
var as = new AppStorage('MyApp');
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer @Quill. I have one more question. With this pattern how can i set local methods and variables which are only available with in the constructor. for an example i want prefix variable to be only available locally but it should be able to refer with in the prototype methods

Comment: @user3405435: If that's really a requirement, then you'll need to stick with your original pattern, effectively making your methods into closures that carry a reference to the "private" prefix variable. Outside of scoping tricks like that, there's no way (AFAIK) to have actual "private" properties on JS objects. That said, if you just want to prevent other code from (easily) changing the prefix, [making it read-only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7757337/defining-read-only-properties-in-javascript) might be enough.

Comment: @user3405435, actually that's where the `this` keyword comes into play. In any prototype (including the constructor) you can define variables to be used throughout any method attached to the prototype. In my example, in the functions `save`, `get` and `return`: `prefix` was changed to `this.prefix`.

Comment: @vivekpoddar: if you see my final example, they're left out.

Comment: Ah, right. Forgot about those, thanks for the reminder.